# How to parse ['A:B:C', 'A:B:D', 'A:C'] into {'A': ['C', {'B': ['D', 'C']} ] }

Tags: python, parsing, data-structures

Essentially I need to write a parser of some product of a markup. It's a list of strings formatted like such:

```
x = [
'A:B:C:D:E',
'A:B:D',
'A:C:E:F',
'B:D:E',
'B:C',
'A:C:F',
]
```

I need to turn it into a python object like so:

```
{
  "B": [
    "C", 
    {
      "D": "E"
    }
  ], 
  "A": [
    {
      "B": [
        "D", 
        {
          "C": {
            "D": "E"
          }
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "C": [
        "F", 
        {
          "E": "F"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can copy above and paste into [this inspector](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) to look at the object hierarchy, and understand what I'm going after. In any regards, it's a nested dictionary combining common keys, and putting items in lists sometimes.

TL;DR - 
I have written a function below

```
splits = [l.split(':') for l in x]

def DictDrill(o):
    # list of lists
    if type(o)==type([]) and all([type(l)==type([]) for l in o]):
        d = dict()
        for group in o:
            if type(group)==type([]) and len(group)>1:
                d[group[0]] = d.get(group[0],[]) + [group[1:]]
            if type(group)==type([]) and len(group)==1:
                d[group[0]] = d.get(group[0],[]) + []
        return DictDrill(d)
    # a dictionary
    elif type(o)==type({}):
        next = dict(o)
        for k,groups in next.items():
            next[k] = DictDrill(groups)
        return next
```

But you'll see that this script is only returning dictionaries and the last item is placed on as a key again with an empty `dict()` as value. If you run my script like `DictDrill(splits)` on the example you will see this:

```
{
  "B": {
    "C": {}, 
    "D": {
      "E": {}
    }
  }, 
  "A": {
    "C": {
      "E": {
        "F": {}
      }, 
      "F": {}
    }, 
    "B": {
      "C": {
        "D": {
          "E": {}
        }
      }, 
      "D": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the useless {} as values
Preferably I need to solve this in python. I know a little C# but it seems very cumbersome to move data around between lists and dictionaries...

Comment: can you elaborate on how the hierarchy is defined? It's not obvious to me after a bit of probing.

Comment: You can do this by building a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: @BrianJoseph so 'A:B:C' and 'A:B:D' should be combined because they share common keys. It should first become {'A': ['B:C','B:D']}. Then the value list can be further combined because of common key 'B'. Result is {'A': {'B': ['C', 'D']}}, where the value no longer has common keys...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
data = ['A:B:C:D:E', 'A:B:D', 'A:C:E:F', 'B:D:E', 'B:C', 'A:C:F']
def to_dict(d):
  if isinstance(d, dict) or not d or any(isinstance(i, (dict, list)) for i in d):
    return d
  return d[0] if len(d) == 1 else {d[0]:to_dict(d[1:])}

def group(d):
   _d = [(a, [c for _, *c in b]) for a, b in gb(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])] 
   new_d =[{a:to_dict(b[0] if len(b) == 1 else group(b))} for a, b in _d]
   return [i for b in new_d for i in (b if not all(b.values()) else [b])]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(group([i.split(':') for i in data]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "A": [
        {
            "B": [
                {
                    "C": {
                        "D": "E"
                    }
                },
                "D"
            ]
        },
        {
            "C": [
                {
                    "E": "F"
                },
                "F"
            ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
    "B": [
        "C",
        {
            "D": "E"
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: The environment I'm in is IronPython 2.7. Is that why it gives me a syntax error for this line `_d = [(a, [c for _, *c in b]) for a, b in gb(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]`. It says unexpected *